# averaging time information

Tags: matlab

I have two cell array with time information:

here is the example:

```
'2012-05-10'
'2012-05-10'
'2012-05-10'
'2012-05-10'
'2012-05-10'
'2012-05-11'
'2012-05-11'

'19:28:27.000'
'19:28:38.000'
'21:57:31.000'
'21:57:37.000'
'21:57:40.000'
'21:57:43.000'
'21:57:50.000'
```

I just needed two time information like i do unique:

```
'2012-05-10'    '19:28:27.000'
'2012-05-11'    '21:57:40.000'
```

I will some time have this too:

```
'2012-05-10'
'2012-05-10'
'2012-05-10'
'2012-05-10'
'2012-05-10'

'19:26:27.000'
'19:26:38.000'
'21:55:31.000'
'21:57:37.000'
'21:55:40.000'
```

How do i go by doing this.

Comment: What are you asking here? Your question is a little unclear

Comment: You should provide more context and explanation. I assume that the same-index entries in each array are parts of the same date time. Your title says you want an average but you are taking the minimum / earliest time in a given day (assuming that in your example you are mistakenly off by one - the earliest time on the 11th would be the next entry)

Comment: Adding to the previous comments, what is the expected result? Please provide a short example of input and expected output...

Comment: Your question is COMPLETELY unclear.  What is input?  What is output?  What is the problem?

Comment: I needed unique day and hour minute and sec does not matter out of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the `unique` function:

```
>> dates = {'01-Jan-2001'; '01-Jan-2001'; '01-Jan-2001'; '02-Jan-2001'};
>> times = {'15:52';'16:03';'17:05';'04:13'};
>> [d idx] = unique(dates);
>> t = times(idx);
>> [d t]
ans = 
    '01-Jan-2001'    '17:05'
    '02-Jan-2001'    '04:13'
```

This method grabs the *last* time associated with each date. If you want to grab the *first* time then you can use this function:

```
function [d t] = uniqueDates(dates,times)
[d idx] = unique(flipud(dates));
reversed_times = flipud(times);
t = reversed_times(idx);
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the strings to vecotrs using [datevec](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datevec.html)(), then drop the min and sec info and convert back to a single string using [datestr](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datestr.html)() and then use unique()

Here is an example but I haven't tested it:

```
dates = ['2012-05-10'
'2012-05-10'
'2012-05-10'
'2012-05-10'
'2012-05-10'
'2012-05-11'
'2012-05-11']

times = ['19:28:27.000'
'19:28:38.000'
'21:57:31.000'
'21:57:37.000'
'21:57:40.000'
'21:57:43.000'
'21:57:50.000']

%this bit might not work, if not just do it with a for loop. It is constructing a vecotr of spaces.
spaces = zeros(size(times,1), 1);
spaces(:) = " ";

%Concatenate the date and time strings with a space character between them.
DateVectors = datevec([dates, spaces, times]);
%discard min and sec
DateVectors(:, 5:6) = 0;
%convert back to strings
DateStrings = datestr(DateVectors);
%find unique values
unique(DateStrings)
```